# Need to get it to display the position of the inputted word, not every word

Tags: python

Here is my code:

```
# This defines the variable 'sent'
sent = 'ASK NOT WHAT YOUR COUNTRY CAN DO FOR YOU ASK WHAT YOU CAN DO FOR YOUR COUNTRY.'

# This splits the sentence into individual words
sen1 = sent.split()

# This tells the program to display the sentence as the individual words
print (sen1)

# Tells the user to input one of the words from the sentence that they would like to find
Word = input(str('Which word would you like to search for?'))

# Changes the user's input to block capitals
Word1 = Word.upper()

# Prints the user's input in capitals
print ("Searching for ", Word1)

# Numbers the words in the sentence starting at (ASK, 0)
position = list(enumerate(sen1))

# Asks the program to check if the user's input is within the defined sentence
if Word1 in sen1:
    # Tells the program to print a certain sentence if the users' inputted word is within the sentence
    print ('Your word is in the sentence at ' , position)

else:
    # Tells the program what to do print if the users' inputted word is not within the sentence
    print ('Your word is not in the sentence')
```

It needs to output the position of the word inputted by the user, rather than the position of every word in the sentence like it does now.